# Read from one text file and write into two text files

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to read from one text file(carsAndBikes.txt) and the write in either cars.txt or bikes.txt
carsAndBikes contains a list of cars and bikes and the first character of each name is C or B (C for Car and B for Bike). So far i have that but its showing cars and bikes content. Instead of the separated content.(CARS ONLY OR BIKES ONLY)

```
   public static void separateCarsAndBikes(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        //complete the body of this method to create two text files
        //cars.txt will contain only cars
        //bikes.txt will contain only bikes    
        
        File fr = new File("C:\\Users\\KM\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Question4\\carsAndBikes.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(fr);                                                             
        String line;
                       
        while(scanFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = scanFile.nextLine();
            if(line.startsWith("C"))
            {
               
                try(PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\KM\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Question4\\cars.txt"))
                {                  
                   printWriter.write(line);                                                                           
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Message" + e);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
                try(PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\KM\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Question4\\bikes.txt"))
                {                                       
                    printWriter.write(line);                  
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Message" + e);
                }               
            }            
        } 
        //close the file
       scanFile.close();      
    }
```

Comment: `if(filename.charAt(0) == C)` ==> is that what you need to test (that the file name starts with a C)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if the input filename starts with a c instead of checking if the line read starts with a c.

You should also open both your output files before your loop, and close them both after the loop.

```
// Open input file for reading 
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\KM\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Question4\\carsAndBikes.txt");      
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))); 

// Open bike outputfile for writing
// Open cars outputfile for writing

// loop over input file contents
String line;
while( line = br.readLine()) != null ) {

    // check the start of line for the character
    if (line.startsWith("C") {
        // write to cars
    } else {
        // write to bikes
    }
}

// close all files
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lennart!

Comment: If this answers your question, it would be appreciated, if you could click the checkmark next to my answer to accept it.
If you need more info, i'm happy to add to my answer to help you :)

Comment: Thank you. Is there another way I can write to a text file apart from the one in my solution?

Comment: I'd suggest that you use a PrintWriter, it makes it much more easy. This is a good example for that: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/printwriter.html

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: One more question. The solution is only printing the last 2 items in the carsAndBikes text file to the cars.txt and bikes.txt. Could it be the the loop or if statement? eg C - Ford to the cars.txt & B - Yamaha to bikes.txt

Comment: I tested it locally, and the lines are split here. Can you update your code in the original post, and add your current code, so I could have a look?

Comment: Two options: tweak the Scanner or use a buffered reader. Since you're not actually scanning, I'd suggest switching to a Reder (see updated answer)